# Unable to add QtPositioning and QtLocation to Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

I try to minimize Android app using ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES. [This](https://github.com/edips/Minimal_QML_Android) example works without any error. However when I add Positioning and Location plugins and libraries the app clashes and closes, the error message is:

```
 W/libuntitled3.so(25548): (null):0 ((null)): QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
W/libuntitled3.so(25548): (null):0 ((null)): qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtPositioning" plugin "declarative_positioning" not found
W/libuntitled3.so(25548):
W/libuntitled3.so(25548): (null):0 ((null)): exit app 0
I/ActivityManager(  556): Process org.qtproject.example.untitled3 (pid 25548) has died.
D/ActivityManager(  556): cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked -- 25548
D/Zygote  (  215): Process 25548 exited cleanly (255)
```

I tried the above for Qt 5.11.0. I also tested the project for Qt 5.10.0 and I get error ""declarative_location" not found". 
I tried to add the missing lib using a few methods separately, it didn't work:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS +=/home/edip/Qt/5.11.0/android_armv7/qml/QtPositioning/libdeclarative_positioning.so
```

and

```
LIBS += -L"/home/edip/Qt/5.11.0/android_armv7/qml/QtPositioning/libdeclarative_positioning.so"
```

and

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_PLUGINS += \
        /home/edip/Qt/5.11.0/android_armv7/plugins/position
```

I don't know what I miss. I don't understand that lib/libQt5Positioning.so and libdeclarative_location.so are installed in lib folder in APK file, but libdeclarative_positioning.so isn't installed in APK file. Is there any way to add the missing libs to pro file? Thanks

pro file:

```
QT += qml positioning location
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES += \
    jar/QtAndroid.jar \
    jar/QtAndroidExtras.jar \
    lib/libQt5Core.so \
    lib/libQt5Gui.so \
    lib/libQt5Network.so \
    lib/libQt5Qml.so \
    lib/libQt5Quick.so \
    lib/libQt5AndroidExtras.so \
    lib/libQt5Positioning.so \
    lib/libQt5Location.so \
    plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so \
    plugins/position/libqtposition_android.so \
    plugins/position/libqtposition_positionpoll.so \
    plugins/styles/libqandroidstyle.so \
    qml/QtPositioning/libdeclarative_positioning.so \
    qml/QtLocation/libdeclarative_location.so \
    qml/QtPositioning/plugins.qmltypes \
    qml/QtPositioning/qmldir \
    qml/QtLocation/plugins.qmltypes \
    qml/QtLocation/qmldir \
    qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir \
    qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so \
    qml/QtQuick/Window.2/libwindowplugin.so \
    qml/QtQuick/Window.2/plugins.qmltypes \
    qml/QtQuick/Window.2/qmldir \
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
Window {
    id:win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title:qsTr("Hello World")
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: yea
        text: win.title
    }
}
```